# How to throttle a fetching createAsyncThunk?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, throttling, toolkit, debouncing

I have a chart component that given props it fetches data and renders accordingly. I have multiple of these charts in the app; this gets me 429 (too many requests) at the same time.

I'm using createAsyncThunk (ChartSlice.js) to fetch but I'm unable to throttle. I've tried creating a middleware but when it comes to filtering the actions passing through I get the following ".../pending", ".../fulfilled", ".../rejected".

I thought of doing the fetch in a parent component but it'd be cleaner to keep the chart taking care of it's own logic so I can just pass the props and let it render automatically (re-usability).

**Parent component**

```
platforms.map((platform) => <ChartComponent platform={platform}/>)
```

**Chart component** being used several times in the app.

```
export const ChartComponent = memo(({ platform }) => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state[platform]);
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchchart({ platform }));
    }
  }, [platform]);

  return (
    <>
      <ApexChart data={data} />
    </>
  );
});
```

**Fetching thunk**

```
 export const fetchchart = createAsyncThunk(
  "chart/fetch",
  async (params, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint(params));
    const data = await response.json();
    thunkAPI.dispatch(
      updateChart({data}));
  }
);
```

**Update**
Still haven't managed to find a way to throttle fetching createAsyncThunk without extracting logic from the re-usable chart component. I did solve the 429 error setting a timeout on the dispatch and adding a fulfilled condition.

```
 useEffect(() => {
if (chartLoaded === "succeeded") {
  setTimeout(() => dispatch(fetchchart({ platform })), 1000);
}, [platform]);
```

Comment: throttle the request in your `useEffect` the lodash library has an out-of-the-box implementation

Comment: It says actions must be plain objects using useEffect(), I'm using react-toolkit. This useEffect() would be created each time the `<ChartComponent />` is rendered throughout the app, that's why I thought a middleware would be neat.
`useEffect(() => {_.throttle(() => {dispatch(fetchchart({ platform }))}, 1000);}[platform]);`

Comment: `throttle` wouldn't have any affect on how redux is dispatching actions. Something else is going on